# parsing XML returned from server

Tags: c#, xml

```
<rsp stat="ok">

<image_hash>ducex</image_hash>
<delete_hash>QXHbCECmDX</delete_hash>
<original_image>http://i.imgur.com/ducex.jpg</original_image>
<large_thumbnail>http://i.imgur.com/ducexl.jpg</large_thumbnail>
<small_thumbnail>http://i.imgur.com/ducexs.jpg</small_thumbnail>
<imgur_page>http://imgur.com/ducex</imgur_page>
<delete_page>http://imgur.com/delete/QXHbCECmDX</delete_page>

</rsp>
```

First off all, can someone help me  start of how to parse this? All i need to do is check the "stat" value. if thats okay , then I need to get the "orginal image" link. I am targetting .NET 4.0 Client Frameowkr however so does that give me access to LINQ to XML?

How would I accomplish this using C#? Any tips to start me off with? 
Thanks

Comment: By returned from server do you mean you are parsing this in the HTML or are you parsing it one the server in C#.  If C# you want to use the xmldoc object

Comment: I think thats irrevelant. I have a string that has that value. I dont think it matters where the string is coming from, however the string will always be in the same structure.

Comment: it's not irrelevant. Coming from a server, you may be given a `Stream` or an `XmlReader`. When you have something richer than a string, you should use it. You should avoid processing XML from strings whenever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to XML. The `xmlInput` variable below would contain your string.

```
string xmlInput = @"<rsp stat=""ok"">
<image_hash>ducex</image_hash>
<delete_hash>QXHbCECmDX</delete_hash>
<original_image>http://i.imgur.com/ducex.jpg</original_image>
<large_thumbnail>http://i.imgur.com/ducexl.jpg</large_thumbnail>
<small_thumbnail>http://i.imgur.com/ducexs.jpg</small_thumbnail>
<imgur_page>http://imgur.com/ducex</imgur_page>
<delete_page>http://imgur.com/delete/QXHbCECmDX</delete_page>
</rsp>
";

var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlInput);
if (xml.Attribute("stat").Value == "ok")
{
    string originalImage = xml.Element("original_image").Value;
}
```

Comment: thanks, my mistake was XElement.Parse(xmlInput); I was trying to use LINQ to XML on a string variable.